# If a port is in the LISTENING state, what is the meaning of the 'Remote Address' field in netstat/TCPView

Tags: networking, port

While using netstat/TCPView to see what connections my PC is making,
I noticed that a lot of the connections whose State is 'LISTENING', have a value for 'Remote Address' which isn't 「*」.

This doesn't make sense to me, because if the port is merely listening, then surely that means nothing is connected to it yet, and therefore there is no Remote Address.

Can anyone explain this to me?